# Can I reset my .snk file password?

Tags: sharepoint, snk

I am now taking over an existing sharepoint project  which has been developing
in a VM enviroment .

I have to enter into the VM enviroment under a specified account. Because there is no one know the .snk file password now. (The creator had left)

I am worry about that if we have to move the develop enviroment into another VM , I couldn't continue develop it .

So I wonder can I recover the .snk file password ? or any other way I can try .

I know may be I could create a new key file , but all the aspx files are stored in SharePoint content database.

If I build a new dll , I have to update the PublicTokenKey of every aspx file in db. It might be make an big impact on my website.

Anyone could give me a safety way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you need the password? Can't you just continue using the same public key as before?

Comment: @Rikard Uppström  Because if I dont know the .snk file password , I can only develop it under a specified account which had successfully passed through the password once before. But the owner had left the company , so no any otherone knows the password. Any another user cannt build it successful.

Comment: Ah.. so you get a password-prompt every time you try to build?

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe this is possible.  Your best bet is to create a new snk file and do a find/replace for the token in your files.  I didn't quite follow what you meant by "updating the PublicTokenKey of every aspx file in the db"  With SharePoint, you should largely be dealing with controls that live as web parts on the page, so the controls would be what you need to update.  Unless you are updating master pages/page layouts, but you should be able to iterate through those and find/replace the references there as well.